# Problem with Checkout ID saved in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

There is a problem with this piece of code in the shopify javascript SDK

```
const cartID = localStorage.getItem('checkoutId');

if( cartID == null || cartID == ""){
    client.checkout.create().then((checkout) => {
        localStorage.setItem('checkoutId', checkout.id); // Store the ID in localStorage
});
}
```

Well there is not a problem with the code itself but with this way of treating the code. It seems that when "X" time passes the checkout ID is no longer working or available so the checkout that once existed, no longer exists. This resulted in an unusable ecommerce website since there was no checkout and the code always tried to access it.

I found out this was the problem since the Chrome browser returned an error stating that no checkout was found ( I do not posses that exact words ). I fixed this clearing the browser data, so the question is :

How do I state in the code to create a new checkout, saved it in local storage, and create a new checkout in 10 days, in order to avoid this from happening again.

Comment: Any user can clear stored data in their own browser. If you need more reliable persistence store it on a server somewhere (your server, cloud storage etc). However unless something in your code or a user clears the data your problem sounds strange

Comment: Nothing you can do can prevent the user from clearing their local data anytime they want. As pointed out above, if you don't like the timeout, it's best to store the data yourself.

Comment: @zfrisch I don't mean to prevent the user from clearing their local data. I just want that when certain time frame passes, update a local storage value. If the user clears the data it doesnt matter, I am not looking for data persistence.

Comment: @charlietfl I am not looking for persistance, I want to update the value after certain time frame. If the user clears its own browser data thats no problem... its even better for me since they are fixing the problem by themselves. The problem relies that Shopify seems to save a checkout for a period of time unknown to me, but the local storage saves the checkout id for ever, so when the user tries to access the checkout with an old checkout id, that checkout no longer exists but it doesn't know since the create function doesn't have an exception to it.

Comment: Ah...OK. Interpreted it as after X time it didn't exist in localStorage which didn't make sense unless user wiped it clean or some other code did

Comment: Can't you just run through local items and make request to see if they are still valid?

Comment: @charlietfl the problem here is that I cannot recreate this error unless a lot of days have passed without me accessing the website... What I could see when I got this weird behavior is that no error was thrown unless I was on Chrome. I could try and catch the error since there is no exception handling in the documentation but that means I have to wait and expect the error to happen again, and I want to avoid that from happening xD..